# how to limit the checkbox checked using icheck jquery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to limit the checkbox checked using iCheck jquery plugin. Please check wiht jsfiddle

```
$('input').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_flat-green',
    radioClass: 'iradio_flat-green',
    labelHover: true,   
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s9916jpy/2/

Comment: if the user selected 4 if he clicks the on 5 th checkbox it should alert or dispay mesage to user

Comment: Could you make it more clear?

Comment: user have to check only 4 other than that if he selected it must alert and not to check the checkbox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/s9916jpy/4/)**

Add an `ifChecked` event to all the `checkbox` with its common class i.e. `.men_checkbox` and check whether `checked checkbox` length is greater than or equal to `limit` which is a **global variable** as below:

```
var limit=4; //change according to your need

$(".men_checkbox").on("ifChecked",function(){
    var checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");//get all the checkbox
    if (checkboxes.filter(":checked").length >= limit) { 
         //if limit is reached disbaled all except checked and #man7
         //else put an alert here instead of below lines.
         checkboxes.not(":checked,#man7").iCheck('disable'); 
    } else {
         //else enable it all
         checkboxes.not(":checked").iCheck('enable'); 
    }
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

To display an `alert` you just need to prevent its default action using `e.preventDefault()` and display the `alert`. Check below code and this **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/s9916jpy/7/)**

```
$(".men_checkbox").on("ifChecked",function(e){
    var checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");
    var $this=$(this);
    if (checkboxes.filter(":checked").length > limit) { 
        alert('Max limit reached');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $this.iCheck('uncheck');
        },1);
    }
});
```

Comment: user have to check only 4 other than that if he selected it must alert and not to check the checkbox

Comment: can we do like this on clicking 5 it should not uncheck other checkbox but should say alert message and uncheck the 5 checkbox

Comment: it checks till 7th checkbox but the limit is 4 right

Comment: could you tell me what is the purpose of using settimeout

Comment: `setTimeout` is basically used to tell `javascript` to run the particular lines inside the context in a **`separate thread`**.. Sometimes it will be not possible to handle all the events synchronously in a single thread..